# Get last record of result set

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Following is the sql query (oracle) that I use to get the last record of the returning result of the select query. Is this the optimum way?

```
SELECT HAZMAT_PLACARD_NOTATION
        INTO v_pcn
        FROM HAZMAT_CLASS_IRF
        WHERE HAZMAT_CD = p_stcc_cd and ROWID = (SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM HAZMAT_CLASS_IRF WHERE HAZMAT_CD = p_stcc_cd);
```

Following is an example result set of the select query where HAZMAT_CD = 4920111 
But the last row with the HAZMAT_PLAYCARD_NOTATION value SPONTANEOUSLY COMBUSTIBLE should be retrieved. That's the objective

[image]

Comment: I think you can use `SELECT TOP 1` and `ORDER BY ROWID DESC` - But I'm not sure in Oracle ;).

Comment: I don't think you can use `ORDER BY` here.  This query seems OK to me.

Comment: Yeah TOP 1 doesn't work in oracle

Comment: Beware of `ROWID`, its order in no way indicates the order of insertion (see: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_find_last_row.htm)

Comment: So what's the solution if there's no column available to determine the latest entry of a result set?

Answer (score 3):

> Get last record of result set

There are many ways:

**Oracle** `Pre-12c` version:

- **ROWNUM** in sub-query and **ORDER BY** in outer query
- **Analytic** function

**Oracle** `12c` version:

- **Top-n Row Limiting feature**

Using **ROWNUM**

```
SELECT HAZMAT_PLACARD_NOTATION
INTO v_pcn
FROM
  (SELECT HAZMAT_PLACARD_NOTATION,
    ROWNUM rn
  FROM HAZMAT_CLASS_IRF
  WHERE HAZMAT_CD = p_stcc_cd
  ORDER BY        <sort_column> DESC
  )
WHERE rn =1;
```

Using **Top-n Row Limiting feature**

```
SELECT HAZMAT_PLACARD_NOTATION
 INTO v_pcn
  FROM HAZMAT_CLASS_IRF
  WHERE HAZMAT_CD = p_stcc_cd
  ORDER BY        <sort_column> DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30321788/3989608) for examples and detailed explanation.

Comment: This is a good explanation. But what's the advantage using the query with ROWNUM you've provided over the query in my question. Is that the optimum way?

Comment: @AsiriLiyanaArachchi Using **ROWNUM** you scan the table only once, and apply ROWNUM on the result set of the sub-query . In your query, you are scanning the table twice, which is not optimal.

Comment: @AsiriLiyanaArachchi Please mark it as answered, would help others.

Comment: I've edited the question. I can't use order by . Given that the query I've mentioned is the only way I could come  up with to get the last row. Any idea?

Comment: I've noticed that in your solution with ROWNUM there may be a mistake based on the question, what we want is the last record of a result set, so by doing the later filtering "WHERE rn =1" you are getting the row with the rownum value of 1 regardless of ordering in the sub-query. In this case using WHERE ROWNUM = 1 would give the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql ,you can try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table` 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

Comment: The OP wants to do an `INSERT INTO` which makes the question a bit trickier than the query you have posted.

Comment: you question is "Get last record of result set"

Comment: This is not mysql  and it's a part of stored procedure. I'm saving returning value to the variable v_pcn

Comment: There is no `LIMIT 0,1` in Oracle

Comment: Yes,this is Mysql Query

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
   ( 
     select * from table order by id desc
   )
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: I don't this this works. Doesn't this return the first row of the result set ?

Comment: it does , but its also why im sorting by whatever ID you need to sort by desc

Comment: Isn't order by executed after rownum?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091849/how-to-use-oracle-order-by-and-rownum-correctly

Answer (score 0):

In older sqlserver versions (<2014) you don't have the ROW_NUMBER at your disposal.

But you can easily use Top 1 and order by desc

```
select top 1 * from tblc2scdocumentcodes where C2scDocumentCode like '%.14.%' and C2scDocumentCode like '%DTP.SO.%' order by C2scDocumentCode desc
```

The query returns a resultset. The order of this resultset is 'reversed' and then limited to 1 record