# sql selecting the newest order date

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to retrieve the newest order and the name of the customer who ordered it:

```
Select fname, lname, orderdate as newestorder
from customer, cusorder
where customer.cid = cusorder.cid
group by fname, lname
having orderdate = max(orderdate)
;
```

the error is ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: select top 1 fname, lname....... from table1, table2, where customer.cid..... order by orderdate desc might work?

Comment: @mrunion top doesn't exist in oracle. `ORA-00979` is an oracle error

Comment: in oracle it is WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure and I didn't Google it first. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @turo Order by + rownum doesn't work well. see [How to use Oracle ORDER BY and ROWNUM correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15091849/119477)

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the error because you've included `orderdate` in the select but you're not grouping by it.

That said it won't do what you want. There are many ways to do what you want. Here is one

```
Select fname, lname, orderdate as newestorder
from customer
    inner join cusorder
     on customer.cid = cusorder.cid

where 
 orderdate = (select max(orderdate) from cusorder)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use join insted point. It is considered good practice. Try this:

```
Select 

fname, lname , max(orderdate) as newestorder
from customer AS c
INNER JOIN cusorder as cu on c.cid = cu.cid
group by fname, lname
order by newestorder desc
;
```

Answer (score 0):

should should be able to just do a max date right on the select query assuming the names are the same.

```
Select fname, lname, max(orderdate) as newestorder
from customer, cusorder
where customer.cid = cusorder.cid
group by fname, lname
```