# Oracle/ExaData RowNum Range returns duplicate rows

Tags: oracle, exadata

I am executing this query on exadata in a for loop of a java program

```
select a, b, c, d from (
        select rownum r, a, b, c, d from foo order by c asc
) where r >= 40001 and r < 50001
```

Here i keep incrementing the numbers by 10000, so in the next loop iteration the numbers would be 50001 and 60001

I take the rows and insert into another database and loop again.

Currently, my code encounters random errors like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '23-ABC@XYZ.COM' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1809)
    at
```

When I check my source (exadata) database, there is only 1 row with a=23 and b = ABC@XYZ.COM. So the source doesn't have any duplication.

when I check my target database, I can see that the row a=23, b = ABC@XYZ.COM has already been inserted in a previous loop iteration. {{I drop and recreate the destination table at the start of the program.}}

So it looks like my window query is returning the same row again and again.

I did lot of search and I am pretty sure that my windowing query should not return duplicates... but it seems like it does

I am not an oracle/exadata expert... so let me know if there is a change that the query above can return the same row when run with different rownum ranges.

Comment: Or updates to the sort column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number() over()` that's actually a window function.
Since `a` and `b` seems to make the record unique, you should try.

```
select a, b, c, d 
  from (
        select row_number() over (order by a,b) as r, 
                a, b, c, d 
          from foo
        ) 
    where r >= 40001 
      and r < 50001;
```

PS: Keep in mind that with this method there should not be any DML's over source table during load.
PS2: `rownum` will never work in this case because is assigned before the order by. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091849/how-to-use-oracle-order-by-and-rownum-correctly).

Comment: Yes, row_number() that's a windows function. rownum it is not

Comment: DML includes inserts and deletes too. If there is a new row that will fall in the first position of the order by, you are going to have duplicates. If there's a delete on a row already transferred you're going to miss another row.