# using of rownum function with ">" sign in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination, oracle10g

I want to select the number of rows which are greater than 3 by rownum function i_e "(rownum>3)"
for example if there are 25 rows and I want to retrieve the last 22 rows by rownum function.
but when I write the

```
select * from test_table where rownum>3;
```

it retrieve no row.
can any one help me to solve this problem.
thanks in advance

Comment: Try as `select * from test_table where rownum<=3`

Comment: Have you tried searching? There are many similar questions, for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091849/how-to-use-oracle-order-by-and-rownum-correctly). Also, you need to define how to decide if a row is "greater" than another

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255) "*Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer **are always false***"

Comment: That's not how ROWNUM works. You could do this with the ROW_NUMBER analytic function but you will still need to decide what 'matters' in terms of a column to order it by.

Answer (score 2):

In RDBMS there is no first or last rows. What you calls "raws" , actually is set(sets), they can be ordered or not. `rownum` is a function, which is just enumerates result set, it makes sense only after set is calculated, to order your set of data (rows) you should do it in your query before `rownum` call, you must tell DB what means for the order in particular select statement.

Comment: One way to achieve you result is - `select * from test_table minus select * from test_table where rownum<=3;`

Comment: @Tom J Muthirenthi And what does this result mean ? give "some rows", oh, no "some rows" is too much, give me 3 less. The word "Relational" in RDBMS 
must mean something, isn't it ?

Comment: `ROWNUM` is not a function - it is a [pseudo-column](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm). Also, you do not need to specify an order - if you do not then Oracle will number the rows in the same order as the rows were retrieved (which can lead to a non-deterministic ordering).

Comment: "@MT0 can't agree with, Yes , according to Oracle documentation rownum is pseudocolumn, but treating them as a functions is not error. "Pseudocolumns" behaves like a table column that's why they called "pseudocolumns", but actually they are implemented as system functions.

Answer (score 2):

It is not working because: for the first row assumes the `ROWNUM` of 1 and since your `WHERE` clause is `ROWNUM>3` then this reduces to `1>3` and the row is discarded. The subsequent row will then be tested against a `ROWNUM` of 1 (since the previous row is no longer in the output and now does not require a row number), which will again fail the test and be discarded. Repeat, ad nauseum and all rows fail the `WHERE`  clause filter and are discarded.

If you want to assign the rows a `ROWNUM` then you need to do this is a sub-query:

```
SELECT *                  -- Finally, in the outer query, filter on the assigned ROWNUM
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,             -- First, in the inner sub-query, apply a ROWNUM
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   test_table t
)
WHERE  rn > 3;
```

Or, if you want to order the results before numbering:

```
SELECT *                  -- Finally, in the outer query, filter on the assigned ROWNUM
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,             -- Second, in the next level sub-query, apply a ROWNUM
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT *              -- First, in the inner-most sub-query, apply an order
    FROM   test_table
    ORDER BY some_column
  ) t
)
WHERE  rn > 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select rownum as rn, t.* from test_table t) where rn > 3
```

see this article for more samples
[On Top-n and Pagination Queries By Tom Kyte](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17asktom-093877.html)

Comment: thanks for answer....