# Pulling names from same table

Tags: sql, oracle

Need name for repaycustomer# column when only customer # is mapped to name.

```
Customer# | CustomerName| RepayCustomer#| Loan#
123       | John Doe    | 456           | 1    
456       | Jane Doe    | 456           | 2
123       | John Doe    | 123           | 3
```

expected results

```
Customer# | CustomerName| RepayCustomer#| Loan# | RepayCustomer 
123       | John Doe    | 456           | 1     | Jane Doe
456       | Jane Doe    | 456           | 2     | Jane Doe
123       | John Doe    | 123           | 3     | John Doe
```

Comment: Which of these are columns and which are tables?

Comment: They are both columns. Need it to kind of loop.

Comment: I'm guessing customer_name is a column from the customer# table?  And/or the Repaycustomer# table?  I think what you are asking is you have two tables customer and repaycustomer.  You need to do a join on those tables, and you want to know how to distinguish between the customer_name column that exists on both tables?

Comment: no they are both on the same table.  Customer and RepayCustomer are 2 different individuals. but repaycustomer is also on the customer column.

Comment: Can you give examples of the type of data in each column?  Is the customer_name included with other data in the columns?

Comment: @ D.L. 

I updated the question to show what I have and what I need to have.

Comment: What tables do you have? Don't you actually have no customer table that contains exactly one row for each customer?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that each `CUSTOMER#` is uniquely associated to a single `CUSTOMERNAME`, a scalar subquery should be all that is required to  generate the expected results.

Below is an example.

First create the test table:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
  CUSTOMER# NUMBER,
  CUSTOMERNAME VARCHAR2(64),
  REPAYCUSTOMER# NUMBER,
  LOAN# NUMBER
);
```

And load the test data:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (123, 'John Doe',456,1);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (456, 'Jane Doe',456,2);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (123, 'John Doe',123,3);
```

Then run query:

```
SELECT
  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER#,
  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNAME,
  CUSTOMER.REPAYCUSTOMER#,
  CUSTOMER.LOAN#,
  (SELECT DISTINCT REPAYCUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNAME
   FROM CUSTOMER REPAYCUSTOMER
   WHERE REPAYCUSTOMER.CUSTOMER# = CUSTOMER.REPAYCUSTOMER# ) AS REPAYCUSTOMER
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

Result:

```
CUSTOMER#  CUSTOMERNAME  REPAYCUSTOMER#  LOAN#  REPAYCUSTOMER  
123        John Doe      456             1      Jane Doe       
456        Jane Doe      456             2      Jane Doe       
123        John Doe      123             3      John Doe
```

But please note if there are ambiguities in the unique association between `CUSTOMER#` and `CUSTOMERNAME` (For example if the first customer# 123 were `John Doe` and the second 123 were`Chewbacca`) this query will (and should) fail.

If the dependency between `CUSTOMERNAME` and `CUSTOMER#` are [consolidated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) 
 the need need for `DISTINCT` here is alleviated.

If possible, it might be worth considering alternative designs to the provided table--this can help make fetches like this reliable, and can help in maintaining the integrity of the data (as well as in constraining the hierarchical relationships between rows).

Comment: I think you can get around the problem with distinct by using row_number(), although your point about consolidation, of course, still holds.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @alexgibbs can be improved a little by limiting the result using row_number() to handle the "ambiguities" he mentions where there are multiple rows with the same CUSTOMER# but with different customer names.  In the case where there are different names, the first alphabetically would always be chosen.

```
SELECT
  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER#,
  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERNAME,
  CUSTOMER.REPAYCUSTOMER#,
  CUSTOMER.LOAN#,
  (SELECT RC2.REPAYCUSTOMER FROM
      (SELECT CUSTOMERNAME AS REPAYCUSTOMER,
              ROW_NUMBER() AS SEQUENCE_NUMBER
         FROM CUSTOMER RC
        WHERE RC.CUSTOMER# = CUSTOMER.REPAYCUSTOMER#
        ORDER BY RC.CUSTOMERNAME) RC2
    WHERE RC2.SEQUENCE_NUMBER = 1)
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

See here for why you can't simply use rownum: [How to use Oracle ORDER BY and ROWNUM correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091849/how-to-use-oracle-order-by-and-rownum-correctly)

Comment: Thanks Guys it worked.

    (Select Distinct Customer.Customer_Name

      
          From CUSTOMER
            Where Customer.Customer_Number  = Psr_Cis 
            And Rownum=1 


              ) As "PSR_NAME",

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name of your table is Customer:

```
SELECT C1.Customer#, C1.CustomerName, C1.RepayCustomer#, C1.Loan#,
C2.CustomerName
FROM Customer C1, (SELECT Customer#, CustomerName
                   FROM CUSTOMER) C2
WHERE C1.RepayCustomer#=C2.Customer#;
```

Comment: I  have a lot of tables joined how can i incorporate this ?