# in my query When RowNum =1 does not get null value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In my query

```
Select AT.PRE_LAST_DATE 
From AUTHORIZATION AT 
Where AT.PROJECT_ID = 5 and AT.PRE_DESIG_ID = 48   
Order By AT.ID Desc;
```

I am getting two dates

1. NULL
2. 17-May-19 00.00.00

But when I use `Rownum = 1`, it does not return null value

```
Select AT.PRE_LAST_DATE 
From AUTHORIZATION AT 
Where AT.PROJECT_ID = 5 and AT.PRE_DESIG_ID = 48 and ROWNUM = 1  
Order By AT.ID Desc;
```

It returns:

1. 17-May-19 00.00.00

Now how do I get the first null value?

Comment: Well only one record has `ROWNUM = 1`, so what were you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting it return me the first value which is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Oracle ORDER BY and ROWNUM correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091849/how-to-use-oracle-order-by-and-rownum-correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` is applied after the `WHERE` clause, which returns only one of the rows in undefined order. To order first, then select the top row, use a subquery:

```
Select PRE_LAST_DATE 
From 
    (Select AT.PRE_LAST_DATE From 
        AUTHORIZATION AT 
        Where AT.PROJECT_ID = 5 and AT.PRE_DESIG_ID = 48
        Order By AT.ID Desc)
Where ROWNUM = 1;
```